# 7805 backfeeds 4v to circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, circuit-design

[image]

I have this circuit design with an Arduino nano and a Nokia 5110 LCD that needs 3.3v. The circuit should work from 12v when connected to JP1.
I added to regulators and 2 rails one with an 7805 and another with 78l33. When the arduino is plugged in the USB it gives voltage to the 5v rail and the 7805 lets 4v pass from output to in. Then across the 78l33 2.5v appears on the display and the display turns on.

Is this a problem? If a put a diode on the output there will be a voltage drop so the output will not be exactly 5v volts. Also what happens when the 12v power is connected to JP1 and also the USB is plugged in will something fry? How can I protect this circuit or is it not a problem? One of the display was not working when powering it with the 12v rail and I don't know if the display is faulty or I made something.

Thank You

Comment: You should never backfeed power to a 78xx; it can damage the regulator. The usual method of avoiding this is putting a diode from output to input; this avoids damaging the regulator, but not backfeeding power. A second diode on the input of the regulator would help with that, I think.

Comment: Thanks, so then something like this would solve it?
https://postimg.cc/HJ7CDpqd

Comment: It might. I'm particularly tired and not at the top of my game today, so there could be something I missed. That's why I didn't make this an answer.

Comment: Ok working perfectly, add it as an answer and I'll mark it. Thank You

Comment: Done. Remember to use a diode that can handle your full load current, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never backfeed power to a 78xx; it can damage the regulator. The usual method of avoiding this is putting a diode from output to input; this avoids damaging the regulator, but not backfeeding power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYBXRr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A second diode on the input of the regulator would help with that, preventing both damage to the regulator and to your source, though it would increase the effective dropout voltage of your regulator by one diode drop, so be aware of that if you're close to the limit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnvCCT.png)</sup>

It goes without saying, but be sure to use a diode that can handle the amount of current you expect your system to use. A 1N4148 might not cut it.